# Can I use #ifdef in a .def?

Tags: dll, conditional-compilation, function

Can I use `#ifdef` sections in a `.def` file for a dll? E.g.:

```
LIBRARY "mydll"
EXPORTS
  checkRequirements
  createDevice
  installDriver
  isPastVersionInstalled
  removeDevice
  #ifdef myVar
  doSomethingElse
  #endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not possible, it is not a file that's pre-processed.  Although I supposed you could by running the preprocessor to generate another .def file and link that one.

The more effective approach is to eliminate the need for a .def file completely.  Use __declspec(dllexport) in your code on the functions that should be exported.  Then any #ifdef in that code will automatically ensure that a function is neither compiled nor exported.

Comment: This looks promising, can you give an example function declaration using this method?

Comment: This is very well documented in the MSDN library, with examples, be sure to look there first.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if .def files can have that exactly, but you can certainly create a file named (for example) `mydll.def.in` and then use the compiler preprocessor to generate the .def file at build time.

On Linux that would be done like this:

```
cpp -DmyVar=1 mydll.def.in > mydll.def
```

I imagine you're doing this on Windows, and I can't help you with that, but it'll be similar.

The only gotcha is that, depending on your compiler, you might need the rest of the file to consist of valid C tokens, and you mustn't have any symbols in the file that can be confused with macros. Gcc has an option `--traditional-cpp` to get around this sort of trouble, and your compiler might have the same sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to solve exactly the same issue. I needed only small differences in otherwise large .def file; differences that change per architecture and between release/debug build. I found the regular C preprocessor unsuitable (and unusable without modifications) for this purpose.

So I ended up writing my own, much simpler, preprocessor for the .def files: [github.com/tringi/defprep](https://github.com/tringi/defprep)

Usage example is in the middle of the page.

The syntax is simple: Rows annotated with `#ABC` or `#ABC=def` at the end of the line will make it into output only if there's `ABC`, or `ABC=def` respectively, on the command line. I usually pass just a couple of Visual Studio macros like `$(ProcessorArchitecture)` and `$(Configuration)`.